# How to split uneven numbers in Python in multiple parts (Password Generator Project)

Tags: python

I am trying to build a Password Generator with Python and I ran into a problem I am struggling with.

Let's assume we have 3 password criteria we like to include:

```
alphabet_lower = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
alphabet_upper = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
```

Then we have a password length.

```
final_pwd_length = 8
```

Now, if the password length is a multiple of 3, I can simply do:

```
if final_pwd_length % 3 == 0:
    final_pwd_length /= 3
    lower_length = int(final_pwd_length)
    upper_length = int(final_pwd_length)
    number_length = int(final_pwd_length)
```

So I can choose equal parts of lowercase, uppercase and numbers for the password.

The problem is, what do I do if `final_pwd_length = 11` or any other number that is not a multiple of 3? How do I determine the values for `lower_length`, `upper_length`, and `number_length` so that they are as close as possible to each other and add up to 11?

I played around with adding +1 depending on the case, but I can't come up with a working solution yet.

Of course, the easy solution would be to only offer multiples of 3 as a choice of length, but I kind of don't want to do that.

Comment: Partly, yes! Although as some have pointed out below, there are better ways to go about that specific case when you create passwords. But this basically answers the initial question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you should consider is that a stricter alternating pattern actually makes your password weaker. If each letter could be any of the lower case, upper case, or digits, your password entropy is 62**length. If it's strictly alternating then your entropy is 26 x lower case + 26 x upper case + 10 x digits, which is much worse.

If you still want it to alternate, you could do this:

```
s = ""
import random as r
password = []
while len(password) < 11:
    if len(password) in [0,3,6,9]:
        password.append(r.choice(alphabet_lower))
    elif len(password) in [1,4,7,10]:
        password.append(r.choice(alphabet_upper))
    else:
        password.append(r.choice(numbers))
password = s.join(password)
print(password)
```

If you have changed your mind about alternating, do this:

```
import random as r
s = ""
password =[]
characters = alphabet_lower + alphabet_upper + numbers
while len(password) < 11:        
    password.append(r.choice(characters))
password = s.join(password)
print(password)
```

This still isn't ideal, however. The passwords are arbitrary and so you can't get them back if you delete them by accident. One way to solve this is to have a cipher: for example, replace "a" with "kNe8". If you generate a cipher and save the cipher somewhere secure, if something goes wrong you can generate the same password by re-typing the cipher manually. It may also be a security benefit to be able to deliberately make recovering the password impossible if you chose to, which this still can do- just delete the cipher. If you're interested in doing this:

```
s=""
import random as r
letters = [c for c in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"]
cipher = []
for j in range(52):
    a = r.choice(letters)
    b = r.choice(letters)
    c = r.choice(letters)
    d = r.choice(letters)
    cipher.append(s.join([a,b,c,d]))
print(cipher)
```

You then replace "cipher = []" with the output of this code, and delete or comment out the rest of the code. Then:

```
def replacer(a,b,c): #replaces every a in c with corresponding b
    out = c
    for j in range(len(out)):
        for m in range(len(a)):
            if out[j] == a[m]:
                out[j] = b[m]
    return(out)  
inp = [c for c in input("Text to be ciphered: ")]
print(s.join(replacer(letters,cipher,inp)))
```

This code will always output the same pseudorandom characters for the same input e.g. "Facebook" and the same cipher.

Comment: Thanks, Daisy, I'll mark this as the answer since it addresses my specific case. I quite like the second code example, it's clean and easy to understand.

Recovering passwords wouldn't be an issue in this case, good to know it's possible tho!

Answer (score 3):

One simple method is to cycle over the input types:

```py
import string
import random

alphabet_lower = string.ascii_lowercase
alphabet_upper = string.ascii_uppercase
numbers = string.digits

password_length = 11

password = ''.join(
    random.choice([alphabet_lower, alphabet_upper, numbers][i%3]) for i in range(password_length)
)
```

This will alternate between the three symbol types, generating a result like:

```
aB0eY3qC3zU
```

Comment: That seems like a very clean way of doing it. I didn't know that you can add those kind of arguments into random.choice().

Comment: `random.choice` will accept any type of index-able iterable, including a string

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather common problem. A common way is to first split in integer parts and later process the reminder. If should normally be less than the number of slots. You only have to arbitrary order the slots and increase them in order up to exhausting the reminder.

If we use a maj, min, numeric decreasing order, we would get:

| password length | maj number | min number | numeric number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 10 | 4 | 3 | 3 |
| 11 | 4 | 4 | 3 |
| 12 | 4 | 4 | 4 |

Alternatively you could use a random order.

But for a random generator (for password), the stricter the rules the lower the final entropy. This is just because rules can only forbid patterns. So unless you need at least one element of each set, the more efficient password generator would be the one that randomly picks a number of elements from the union of all 3 sets. And if you only need at least one element of each set, I would just add a requirement of at least 8 elements and just pick at random from the whole set of size 62. Then I would control whether the requirement of at least one from each set is satisfied and if it is not just iterate...